# Materialize css - change position of toast dialog

Tags: javascript, css, html, materialize

I am using Materialize css (www.materializecss.com). Want to change position of toast dialog. In smaller screens it is on proper position. For wide screen and box layout it goes to right corner out of my layout. (http://materializecss.com/dialogs.html)

When toast get triggered, it appends "`<div id="toast-container"></div>`" in body. I don't want to append it in body. I want it in specific div.

Comment: Can you provide us with some code so we can help you...

Comment: Check http://materializecss.com/dialogs.html, You will find the demo. i want toast example on specific position

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm interested by an answer to this **very clear** question.

Comment: ManishRane if @NiZa's answer was helpful, please mark it as accepted. :)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The position of the toast dialog can be changed by setting the dafault values of `#toast-container` to `auto` with `!important`.

For example, if you want the opposite position of the default on a desktop screen, change it to:

```css
#toast-container {
  top: auto !important;
  right: auto !important;
  bottom: 10%;
  left:7%;  
}
```

- Using `!important` is **is** necessary otherwise `materialize.css` will override it
- Using `position:absolute;` or `position:fixed;` is **not** necessary

---

**Demo of version 0.97.6**

```js
Materialize.toast('I am a toast!', 4000);
```

```css
#toast-container {
  top: auto !important;
  right: auto !important;
  bottom: 10%;
  left:7%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: If you want to move the toast to the top right, you actually do need to use `bottom: auto !important;` and `left: auto !important;` or else they will be overridden by the default values from materialize.css.

Comment: You are right. I did'nt realize that the demo is showing on a smaller screen. Thanks for your feedback. Changed the answer.

Answer (score 3):

To set toast position at center of the document, you can add this style:

```
#toast-container {
    min-width: 10%;
    top: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    transform: translateX(50%) translateY(50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the position of the dialog, you can directly use css to style it.

```
#toast-container {
    position: fixed !important;
    bottom: 0px !important;
    left: 0px !important;
}
```

The '!important' might be unnecessary.

Comment: Not required to specify `position: fixed` as it is already defined for `#toast-container` inside materializecss styles. But you have to replace `top` property by default one to avoid it applied in combination to `bottom`. To remove it: `top: inherit !important;`

Answer (score 0):

just throw it into a relative div, it looks like that lib will not create add it into the body end if it already exists.

```
<div style="position: relative">
....
<div id="toast-container"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This won't work without also setting #toast-container to ```position: absolute```, as ```position: fixed``` will ignore parent positioning.